# Clearing CSS Style of jQuery Mobile with LESS CSS

Tags: jquery, css, styling, jquery-mobile

I am trying to put a Facebook Connect png image to the header of a jQuery Mobile app. However, due to default styling, the image is put on a button.

How could I reset the style for just a particular image? Should I use use jQuery to remove the class when the '$(document).ready()' is fired?

I am using LESS CSS so should I use it to write a reset class for that particular element? Is there a pre-made reset class for LESS?

Thanks!

Comment: You've mentioned 2 viable options in your question, so why not give those a try? I would recommend the CSS option as it doesn't rely on JavaScript. As far as I know, there is no LESS reset class, but you could reset it yourself easily.

Answer (score 1):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

*Last topic in this page:*

"If you need to to create a header that doesn't follow the default configuration, simply wrap your custom styled markup in a container div inside the header container and the plugin won't apply the automatic button logic so you can write custom styles for laying out the content in your header."

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile supports header customization.

I think the best example to follow is the main page in docs. Everything is there in the sources: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/